# Enterprise Library Logging Application Block (LAB) not working when configured in external file

Tags: c#, .net, logging, app-config, enterprise-library

#### app.config

```
<configuration
    <configSections>
        <section name="logging" type="Micrtosoft.Practices.Enterpr...">
...

<logging configSource="logging.config" />
```

#### logging.config

```
<logging>
    <listeners>
...
```

#### Exception

InvalidOperationException: "The configuration section for Logging cannot be found in the configuration source."

#### Possible mistakes?

- logging.config available? - Check
- Typos? - Check
- Other blocks working with config in different file? (EAB, Unity) - Check

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems like the Enterprise Library Logging Application Block doesn't score for types and namespaces, but for a section called "loggingConfiguration" - how stupid is that?